# a form inside another and ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, forms

hello I have the following code that tries to show the field "name" in the div "target2", but for this I use a form within another form I think is the problem. But I don't see a way to fix it.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" id="fuera">
        <div id="target1">
            
        </div>
    <button type='button' id="botonFuera">EnviarElDeFuera</button>   
    </form>
    <div id="target2">
        
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

otro.php

```
<form method="post" id="dentro">
    <input type='hidden' id='nombre' name='nombre' value='hola'>
    <button type='button' id="botonDentro">EnviarElDeDentro</button> 
</form>
```

otroMas.php

```
<?php
echo($_POST["nombre"]);
?>
```

ajax.js

```
(document).on('ready',function(){    
    $('#botonFuera').click(function(){
    var url = "otro.php";
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,   
       data: $('#fuera').serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       { 
         $('#target1').html(data);             
       }
       });
    });
    
$(document).on('click',':button', function (evt) {       
    if(this.id=='botonDentro')
    {
    var url = "otroMas.php";
    $.ajax({                        
       type: "POST",                 
       url: url,                     
       data: $('#dentro').serialize(), 
       success: function(data)             
       { 
         $('#target2').html(data); 
       }
       });
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Nested forms are not valid. Either change `otro.php` so it just returns the inputs without the form, or remove the form around `target1` in `index.php`.

Comment: i changed otro.php and it worked, thanks!